# how to select column name that is not in group by clause

Tags: sql-server, subquery

```
SELECT  [a],[b],[c],COUNT(*) AS Hits
FROM [dbo].[ta] join [dbo].[tb] on [tb].[id] = [ta].[id] 
where GROUP BY [a],[b],[c]
```

I want to select column c , but not in group by cluase? 
because column "c" is returned a not suifficient record when as in group by clause

---

My current query is

```
SELECT top 20 [headshot],
              [athleteId],
              [athleteName],
              COUNT() AS Hits 
    FROM [dbo].[tblRep_Usecase2] 
    join [dbo].[tblRep_Login] on [tblRep_Login].[ID] = [tblRep_Usecase2].[ID] 
    where athleteName != 'NULL' 
    and headshot != 'NULL' 
    and headshot != '' 
    and convert(date,[tblRep_Usecase2].[insertDate]) >='11/9/2015' 
    and convert(date,[tblRep_Usecase2].[insertDate]) <='11/9/2015' 
    and [tblRep_Usecase2].[appsportid]='41' 
GROUP BY [headshot],[athleteId],[athleteName] 
HAVING COUNT()>1 order by Hits DESC
```

Comment: Can you be more clear? From which table are you selecting each of a, b, and c?

Comment: You can't obviously & logically remove [c] from GROUP BY if you want to SELECT its original values. When multiple [c] values are present for a given [a] & [b] combination there is no way to "magically" merge them into a single record - you need to either aggregate by [c] together with [a] and [b] (to get several records for each separate [c] value) or aggregate the values by using a function like max(), min(), etc. as per your case ...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : You can't.

Longer answer : You have to apply a formula to define how the "c" data is discriminated.

For instance, if you have a table about kids like

```
|a      |b      |c        |
|-------|-------|---------|
|Bob    |Sarah  |Amanda   |
|Bob    |Sarah  |Steve    |
|Bob    |Amanda |Sarah Jr.|
```

You ask him the number of kids of each couples (so Bob+Sarah = 2, Bob+Amanda=1), but then you also ask him the name of a kid. Since he cannot tell you which kid you want, he cannot give you your result.

In this case, maybe Bob, Sarah, Amada, Steve and Sarah Jr are in a table elsewhere with their age. so if you want only the oldest child, you would need to return a,b,"subquery","count". Depending on the situation, a simple aggregate function like MAX/MIN also works.

Comment: here is my query , i dont know why thay should return me 2 record of Adrian Adams?SELECT top 20 [headshot],[athleteId],[athleteName],COUNT(*) AS Hits
   FROM [dbo].[tblRep_Usecase2] join [dbo].[tblRep_Login] on [tblRep_Login].[ID] = [tblRep_Usecase2].[ID] 
   where athleteName != 'NULL' and headshot != 'NULL' and headshot != '' and convert(date,[tblRep_Usecase2].[insertDate]) >='11/9/2015' 
   and  convert(date,[tblRep_Usecase2].[insertDate]) <='11/9/2015' and [tblRep_Usecase2].[appsportid]='41'
   GROUP BY [headshot],[athleteId],[athleteName] HAVING COUNT(*)>1 order by Hits DESC

Comment: Well, let me put it this way : If removing athleteName from the GroupBy clause would change your result, then that means at any one point, athleteId+headshot returns more than 1 atheleteName result.

EDIT : Conversely, if atheleteId is deterministic based on headshot and athleteId, then you should simply add it to the `GROUP BY` clause